# how to compare arraylist with list<string[]> java

Tags: java

```
    List<String[]> sarray;
    ArrayList<ContentTable> currentData=new ArrayList<ContentTable>();

    //here sarray is initialized with data
    sarray = reader.readAll();


    for(String[] arr : sarray) 
        {
          System.out.println("array data "+ Arrays.toString(arr));
        }

        for(ContentTable ct : currentData)
        {
            System.out.println("list data "+ct.getId() +" "+ ct.getSubid() +" "+ct.getChpid()+" "+ct.getSec_name()+" "+ct.getContent());
        }
```

**Output for 1 result of array and list :**

**array data ->** `[9, 10, 83, Concepts: 1-10, <p>We&#x2019;ll discuss many of the concepts in this chapter in depth later. But for now, we need a brief review of these concepts to equip you for solving exercises in the chapters that follow.</p>]`

**list data ->** `9 10 83 Concepts: 1-10 <p>We&#x2019;ll discuss many of the concepts in this chapter in depth later. But for now, we need a brief review of these concepts to equip you for solving exercises in the chapters that follow.</p>`

```
 //fields with getters and setters in ContentTable Class
        public class ContentTable {

            int id;
            int subid;
            int chpid;
            String sec_name;
            String content;
          }
```

Now what I want to achieve is to create two lists ,

```
ArrayList<ContentTable> updatedData=new ArrayList<ContentTable>();
ArrayList<ContentTable> addedData=new ArrayList<ContentTable>();
```

these would be filled with data after comparison of `sarray` and `currentdata` in such a way that,

if `ct.getSec_name()` or `ct.getContent()` at a particular index in `currentdata` is not equal to the data present in `sarray` then it would be added to `updatedData`

And,

if `ct.getId()`,`ct.getSubid()`,`ct.getChpid()` at a particular index is not equal to any of `sarray` data then it would be added to addedData

What would be the elegant way to do this with lesser complexity and I want to do it fastest as it might take time to compare each element in `Arraylist currentData` to compare with each element in `ArrayList sarray`.

Comment: You'll have to compare each element. Clean way would be to create comparing functions to identify updated and added data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, a better solution for my problem was to not compare a `List<String[]>` to `ArrayList` , but to convert `List<String[]>` to another `Arraylist` and then compare the new `Arraylist` against the older one. And that's quite simple and easier approach , I found.

```
                for(String[] arr : sarray) 
                {
                  ContentTable data=new ContentTable();

                  for(String s : arr)   
                  {
                         data.setId(Integer.parseInt(s));
                         data.setSubid(Integer.parseInt(s));
                         data.setChpid(Integer.parseInt(s));
                         data.setSec_name(s);
                         data.setContent(s);
                  }
                  newData.add(data);
                }
```

Now, newData is having the fresh data that I want to compare against currentData.

Answer (score 0):

How about wrapping each element in array to Content. Now adding these content objects to Set. Iterate over the ArrayList and for each element in array list, check if its present in the set. If not update the addedData. If yes, get that object and compare both the content objects using equals.

Note that you would anyway override the hashCode and equals in Content type to make this(Set) work.

The one time activity that you do in the beginning will take time, which is getting the set ready. But once this set is ready, look ups with be really fast.

Comment: any idea over the comparison of `list<Custom>` and `list<String[]>` , that is the most annoying thing here. A code sample will do the job thanks

Comment: Well, you can write one method that iterates over the list<Custom>, than for each custom, you can iterate over the list<String[]>(naive approach).

Comment: but when I iterate over list<String[]> then it has to be iterated again for every string[] object again and then the comparison has to be done , that is really annoying me if I am doing it right or not.

Comment: exactly, what you are doing is right. And thats what i meant by one time activity. Once you have these wrapped up in Content, job becomes lot more easier.